# Agregar nodo a una lista enlazada y escribir la lista en un archivo .csv?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código, lo que hago es leer un dataset con el formato .csv y pasar su información a nodos enlazados.

Resulta que quiero añadir un nuevo nodo a la lista enlazada que tengo y reescribir nuevamente el dataset con el nuevo registro, es decir con el nuevo nodo. La idea es que que verifique si ya existe el registro, si no existe, lo añade.

Supongo que toca encolar el  nodo (con sus atributos) a la lista pero no encuentro la manera de añadirlo a la lista y escribirlo en el dataset.

Aquí lee la linea y la asigno a un nodo. La linea tiene varios atributos separados por ";". También hago una prueba de lectura.

```
package controller;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.soap.Node;
import model.Nodo;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
public class Datos<E> {

public static String PATH = "resources\\data.csv";

private FileReader fr = null;
private BufferedReader br = null;
private Nodo<String> node = null;

public Datos() {
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(PATH);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String lineaActual;
        try {               
            while((lineaActual = br.readLine()) != null) {
                node = new Nodo<String>(lineaActual);

                System.out.println(node.getTitulo());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Datos d = new Datos ();

}
}
```

La interfaz.

```
package interfaces;

public interface INodo <E> {
    public E obtenerId();
}

//
```

Y por ultimo el nodo.

```
package model;

import interfaces.INodo;

public class Nodo <E> implements INodo<E> {
private E elemento;
private Nodo<E> siguiente;  
private String titulo, estudio, estado, versiones, precio, clasificacion, 
anio, genero, fechaPublicacionDVD, id;
public E getElemento() {
    return elemento;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public String getEstudio() {
    return estudio;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public String getVersiones() {
    return versiones;
}

public String getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public String getClasificacion() {
    return clasificacion;
}

public String getAnio() {
    return anio;
}

public String getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public String getFechaPublicacionDVD() {
    return fechaPublicacionDVD;
}


public Nodo(E pElem) {
    elemento = pElem;
    String[] aux = elemento.toString().split(";");
    titulo = aux[0];
    estudio = aux[1];
    estado = aux[2];
    versiones = aux[3];
    precio = aux[4];
    clasificacion = aux[5];
    anio = aux[6];
    genero = aux[7];
    fechaPublicacionDVD = aux[8];
    id = aux[9];
    siguiente = null;
}

public void enlazarSiguiente(Nodo<E> n) {
    siguiente = n;
}

public Nodo<E> obtenerSiguiente(){
    return siguiente;
}

@Override
public E obtenerId() {
    return (E) id;
}


}
```

Una mano, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues agregale un metodo agregar a tu clase nodo.

```
public void agregarNodo(E e) {
  Nodo<E> nuevo = new Nodo<E>(e);
  Nodo curr = this;
  while(curr.siguiente != null) {
    curr = curr.siguiente;
  }
 curr.siguiente = nuevo;
```

}

Mira un ejemplito:
https://repl.it/@maxmedina05/PerfectQuirkyLaw

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Sabes como implementarlo en otra clase distinta?. La idea en agregar un nodo completo (con su atributos), es decir agregar un "E nodo" a la lista.

Comment: No importa si esta en otro clase será el mismo algoritmo. El codigo mas o menos será muy similar.

Comment: Max ya pude implementar en el algoritmo, el problema es que no se como hacer la instacia del nodo para enviarlo como atributo y añadirlo a la lista, como estoy usando genericidad no se muy bien como hacer la instancia y setear los atributos de este para enviarlo.

Comment: Listo, ya lo pude implementar. Gracias.